# 'cache ... miss' when running rails app on windows in 'production' mode using thin + Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

I've got rails app run on windows in 'development' mode using thin + Nginx,
the command is `thin start`, it works well!

BUT when I run `thin -e production start`, the app is started, but I got 'cache ... miss', see below:

```
C:\mytest3>thin -e production start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
cache: [GET /employees/1] miss
cache: [GET /employees] miss
cache: [GET /employees/list] miss
cache: [GET /employees/show] miss
....
```

I don't know what's going on, anyone could help? thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm curious about this case at well. In the pass, I experienced similar problem (cache missed) with Passenger and the fix is to grant write permission to cache folder (tmp/cache) of the app. But trying that for thin and it doesn't help.